# Forcing Win 7 Windows Explorer to format windows correctly

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

You can ask Windows 7 to remember the Windows Explorer (WE) windows that were open when it last shut down, and it will then restore all of those WE windows the next time the system is booted.  What Win 7 does not do is remember exactly how each WE window was set up (position, size, sizes of panes, etc). This omission forces one to manually restore all of this every time one reboots.

I seek a way to ether enhance WE so that it will do this automatically, or find a way to save the configuration information at shut-down time and "push" the saved data into each WE window at boot time, so that the WE windows are restored accurately and correctly.  Best would be a way to remember the exact parameters for each folder on the HD and restore the WE windows appropriately each time a folder is opened by WE.  A database of sorts might be required.

This might be achieved through registry hacks, or by writing software that runs at shutdown, boot time, or the entire time the system is running.

Answer (score 0):

Most nVidia and ATI have window manager software that allow to save/restore the icons and windows position/size.
Or try this little software:
http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html